# Do wall USB cubes have resistors in them?

Tags: resistors, usb, usb-device

Do these have resistors in them? (Picture of a Wall USB Cube Thingy) I'm really not sure the name of these, but I know some old EU ones have resistors so I wanted to know.

[image]

Comment: You mean ONLY a resistor? They are taking 120V AC to 5VDC. There is all sorts of circuitry in them.

Comment: They have many different components in them, including, but not limited to, resistors, capacitors, diodes, transformers, and ICs. Why do you want to know?

Comment: I think it would be feasible (at the large quantities those are made) that they don't have *discrete* resistors, but all voltage division functionality is integrated in ICs and damping resonances is omitted for the sake of cost.

Comment: the `Wall USB Cube Thingy` is a power supply

Comment: Well, it can be also capacitive dropper(especially cheapest ones) ... So, no transformer or ic... Only capacitors, resistors and diodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question you're getting at is, do these cubes use a *dropping resistor*. That is, do they produce 5V from line input by inserting a series resistance to reduce the voltage?

Answer: emphatically, **no**. That would be completely unrealistic for a 5-10W supply like these wall cubes. They're much more complex than that.

To fit in such a small size yet deliver that much power, they're obliged to be switch-mode power supplies that do the following:

- rectify line-voltage AC to DC
- step down that high voltage DC to low voltage DC using a converter

So they will have at minimum:

- a diode bridge,
- a controller IC (or some means to chop the rectifed DC to...)
- a transformer
- some filtering
- some feedback from the output

There may be a resistor or two for support, but not for doing the actual 120V to 5V conversion.

Here's a tear-down of a bunch of them: http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html

And what a low-parts-count circuit looks like:

[image]

From here: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1015-d.pdf

(The photo transistor on the left and LED on the right are usually in one package. This is the feedback path.)

Besides being efficient and compact, this switcher design offers something very important: isolation from mains. The transformer is what provides this isolation, and is often where cheap USB cubes scrimp: they will have high, even dangerous amounts of primary-to-secondary leakage, because of incorrect winding design and/or not enough insulation.